# Фонетический разбор слов

Tags: фонетика

Как будет выглядеть звук "о" при транскрибации слова "радио"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это слово иностранного происхождения, а в них иногда не наблюдается редукция [о], ср.: поло [по’ло].

Радио — [ра’д’ио].

Действительно, в таких словах может произноситься редуцированный [ъ], однако это случается скорее в живой, беглой речи. Полное произношение — это звук [о].

Answer (score 3):

Из словаря [**Каленчук М.Л., Касаткин Л.Л., Касаткина Р.Ф. *Большой орфоэпический словарь русского языка. Литературное произношение и ударение начала XXI века: норма и её варианты.* М., 2012**]:

> **РА́ДИО** \ \ **ра́ди[ə]** *и допуст.* ра́ди[о]

Т. е. основной, наиболее распространённый вариант – [ə],

допустимый, менее употребительный вариант – [о].

**[ə]** – безударный гласный среднего подъёма, произносящийся, например, на месте букв *а, о* в словах *паруса́* – п[ə]руса́, *посиде́ть* – п[ə]сиде́ть, *вы́дана* – вы́д[ə]на, *вырос* – выр[ə]с.

ДЛЯ СПРАВКИ:

Гласный **[ə]** «шва» и **[ъ]** «ер» – один и тот же звук, по-разному обозначаемый в разных транскрипциях.

Answer (score 2):

В отдельных словах иноязычного происхождения на месте буквы о в заударном слоге после гласных произносится гласный [о] (а в настоящее время встречается - [ъ]): какао, радио, хаос, адажио (произносится [какáо] или [какáъ], [рáдио] или [рáдиъ], [хáос], [адáжио] или [адáжиъ]). Гласный [о] или [а/ъ] также может произноситься в сложных словах с первой частью гéо-, бúо- и др., например: геоботаника (может произноситься ге[о]- и ге[ъ]-; биостимулятор (может произноситься би[о]-, би[а]-, би[ъ]-).

[После гласных](http://www.philol.msu.ru/~fonetica/orfoepija/glasnie/1m.htm)

Я бы предпочла Ъ.